# CSS Menu won't show through nested Divs in IE7

Tags: css, html, menu, nested, drop-down-menu

If you look at the menu for this site: http://writershore.com/ltlaw/

The menu looks great in Firefox, Chrome, etc, but in IE7 the menu drop downs don't break through the nested DIVs.

Is this an overflow issue? A z-index issue? I've tried variations of both and doesn't fix the result in IE.

Thanks for any ideas!

Answer (score 2):

The HTML code is broken. For starters you have two `<html>` tags. This will make the page render in quirks mode, which makes a dramatic difference for IE.

Fix the obvious errors in the html, then [validate](http://validator.w3.org/) the page to see if there are any more problems in the code.

Answer (score 1):

IF form elements or  boxes are showing over top of the DIVs such as calendar popups it's not a bug in the javascript - it's a bug/feature of browsers. See this [explanation](http://www.webreference.com/dhtml/diner/seethru/)